# Tikz: resize node to same end point as other node which has unknown height

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Suppose I have a node which contains a scaled-to-width image (ratio unknown). So the height is unknown. Now I want to add 2 nodes left of it with the same y and same height as this 'unknown height picture'

So this:

[image]

**MWE (in reality the height of 5cm is unknown)**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum height=5cm,minimum width=5cm] (scaledImageHeightUnknown) at (2cm,2cm) {Image};
\node[draw] (textLeftOfScaledImage) at (scaledImageHeightUnknown.north west)[anchor=north west] {Directly left of Image};
\node[draw] (textLeftOfText) at (textLeftOfScaledImage.north west) {Directly left of Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Use a fit node with inner sep=0pt. Make it to fit north and south anchors from desired node, fix a minimum width and shift it or anchor where you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just elaborating @ignasi's terse comment recommending to *Use a fit node with inner sep=0pt. Make it to fit north and south anchors from desired node, fix a minimum width and shift it or anchor where you want.*

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=5cm]{somepicture}{example-image-a}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm ,draw] (pic) {\pgfuseimage{somepicture}};
  \node[inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, draw,
    fit=(pic.north)(pic.south),minimum width=1cm,anchor=east,
    label=center:B] (leftpic) at (pic.west) {};
  \node[inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, draw,
    fit=(pic.north)(pic.south),minimum width=1cm,anchor=east,
    label=center:C] (leftleftpic) at (leftpic.west) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Following @ignasi's second comment we use `label=center:...` for positioning the labels instead of putting them between the braces at the end of the `\node` command, to center them properly.

Comment: Thanks, I think this solution is the easiest to follow/understand/recycle.

Comment: @robert As you can see `B` and `C` are misplaced. If you look at `fit` section will see that it's better to use `label=center:...` and not the regular text field (`{...}`) for fitting nodes.

Comment: @Ignasi I've modified the solution accordingly, for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt,
   box/.style = {draw,inner ysep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
                 minimum height=#1}
                    ]
\node (image) [inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}};
\path   let \p1 = ($(image.north)-(image.south)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y1,\x1)} in
        node (n1) [box=\n1-2\pgflinewidth,left=of image] 
                                {\rotatebox{90}{box left of image}}
        node (n2) [box=\n1-2\pgflinewidth,left=of n1]
                                {\rotatebox{90}{box left of Text}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

First I include image in node, than measure node height in this value use in defining left boxes (minimum) heights. Text in this nodes is rotated by help `\rotatebox` macro from `graphicx` package.

Comment: If you draw the first node, `box=\n1-1\pgflinewidth` seems a better choice...